# What is other way to use any variable in page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, viewstate

I am developing one web application. In that i want to use variable's value in page. One way is to store that variable value in ViewState and use its value in page.
But is there any other way to use Variable's value through out the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a global scopped variable

```
protected globalCompanyName { set;get;}
```

but this thing will not keep the value across postbacks.

Session variable ( Available not only in currect page, but thru out the user session)

```
Session["companyName"]="Microsoft";
```

Session values be there across postbacks

Comment: ohh ok. Global variable is fine but is it feasible to use in every page?

Comment: @BrijeshPatel : It depends on your scenario. Ususally if it is going to be in every page, i will add that to my base class and inherit the rest from that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HiddenField, which I think is great for you.

You can also use session variable, but if you create two much of those, it can slow down you user experience.

Of course, you might also store information in the query string, but I don't thing you need that.